# Parse html - CURL and regular expression

Tags: php, regex, curl

How to get text: "Text example max" from:

```
<td valign="top" align="left">

    <a href="/server?tree=xabaf"
    class="normal"> Text example max </a>

</td>
```

using regular expression?

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$ch = curl_init('http://www.site.com?id=325235');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$sss = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match_all("#class="normal"?</a>$#", $sss, $arr);
```

Comment: So why do you even want to do this with a regular expression? Why not use any of the other available techniques to parse HTML?

Comment: Wow, I got an instant flashback of reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/813718

Comment: Apart from the fact that you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML, you need to show what you have tried doing before expecting others to help.  This is not a code generation site.

Comment: Great, @RemcoOverdijk. thanks for posting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using REGEX

```
$text = "<a href='/server?tree=xabaf' class='normal'> Text example max </a>
";
$regex_pattern = "/<a href=\"?\'?(.*)\"?\'?>(.*)<\/a>/";
preg_match_all($regex_pattern,$text,$matches);
```

PHP's DOM

```
$text = "<a href='/server?tree=xabaf' class='normal'> Text example max </a>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){
    echo $link->textContent;
}
```

Use DOM and not regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no other text, applying [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) is enough.

```
$str ='<td valign="top" align="left">

    <a href="/server?tree=xabaf"
    class="normal"> Text example max </a>

</td>';

$str = trim(strip_tags($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.site.com?id=325235';

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);

$html = str_get_html($str);

$content = $html->find('div[class=normal]');
echo $content->innertext;
```